# Why can't an F# class method call another method in the same class when an interface is being implemented?

Tags: f#

In the following demo code why can't MyMethod2 make a call to MyMethod1?

```ml
type IMyClass =
    abstract member MyMethod1 : unit -> unit
    abstract member MyMethod2 : unit -> unit

type MyClass() =
    interface IMyClass with
        member this.MyMethod1() =
            printfn "MyMethod1 called"
        member this.MyMethod2() =
            printfn "MyMethod2 called"
            this.MyMethod1()
```

If I drop the interface it works fine.

```ml
type MyClass() =
    member this.MyMethod1() =
        printfn "MyMethod1 called"
    member this.MyMethod2() =
        printfn "MyMethod2 called"
        this.MyMethod1()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F# interface implementations are always [explicit](https://firstclassthoughts.co.uk/Articles/Programming/ExplicitAndImplicitInterfaceImplementationInFSharp.html), meaning that you must cast the object reference to the interface type before you can access its members, like this:

```ml
        member this.MyMethod2() =
            printfn "MyMethod2 called"
            (this :> IMyClass).MyMethod1()
```

Alternatively, you can mimic an implicit interface implementation by defining the method on the class type:

```ml
type MyClass() =
    member this.MyMethod1() =
        printfn "MyMethod1 called"
    member this.MyMethod2() =
        printfn "MyMethod2 called"
        this.MyMethod1()
    interface IMyClass with
        member this.MyMethod1() = this.MyMethod1()
        member this.MyMethod2() = this.MyMethod2()
```

Note that [explicit interface implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation) in C# works the same way:

```cs
using System;

interface IMyClass
{
    void MyMethod1();
    void MyMethod2();
}

class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    void IMyClass.MyMethod1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyMethod1 called");
    }
    
    void IMyClass.MyMethod2()
    {
         Console.WriteLine("MyMethod1 called");
         this.MyMethod1();   // error CS1061: 'MyClass' does not contain a definition for 'MyMethod1'
    }
}
```